# Zabbix trigger for /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Tags: linux, monitoring, zabbix

I want to create a trigger for monitoring sshd_config changing.
I open "/etc/passwd has been changed on {HOST.NAME}", copy expression from it, create new trigger, paste expression. It was saved successfully. Expression:

```
{Template OS Linux:vfs.file.cksum[/etc/passwd].diff(0)}>0
```

But now if i change `/etc/passwd to /etc/ssh/sshd_config` in expression - zabbix tells me:

Incorrect item key "vfs.file.cksum[/etc/ssh/sshd_config]" provided for trigger expression on "Template OS Linux".

Why?

**`Zabbix` version: 2.4**

Answer (score 2):

It is only possible to create a trigger for existing items. Therefore, you should first create `vfs.file.cksum[/etc/ssh/sshd_config]` item, and only then a trigger for it:

```
{Template OS Linux:vfs.file.cksum[/etc/ssh/sshd_config].diff(0)}>0
```

Attempting to create a trigger for a non-existing item fails with the error you described.